# PHP Rounding Issue When Dividing by 100

Tags: php, rounding

I have a value coming from an array that needs to be converted to a percentage.  My issue is that when I divide by 100 I seem to lose the number after the decimal point.  For example, I need 56.5 to become .565 and this makes it .56.

I've tried using round() number_format(), etc. to no avail.

```
$yearnow = date("Y");
$ratedate = $mileagerates->Rates->Year;
$rateamount = $mileagerates->Rates->Mileage_Rate;

if ($yearnow == $ratedate) {
  $currentyear = $ratedate;
  $currentamount = $rateamount / 100;
} else {
  $currentyear = "";
  $currentamount = 0;
}
echo $currentyear;
echo $currentamount;
```

Comment: I dont see round, or number_format in your code

Comment: That's because they didn't work.  The line causing the issue is:
`$currentamount = $rateamount / 100;`

Comment: Show us the values for $currentyear, $rateamount and $currentamount doing var_dumps; but unless you've found some weirdly obscure bug that nobody else in the world has ever encountered it's hard to see what you mean

Comment: Have you tried dividing by 100.0 ?

Comment: The problem does not appear to be math.  Show us the values of those variables prior to running your division.

Comment: @Br.Bill shouldn't make any difference at all

Comment: _shouldn't_. I _shouldn't_ have a sore shoulder.

Comment: @Br.Bill - please explain then how it would help? It doesn't force casting to float in any way that dividing two integers (e.g. 1 / 4) wouldn't

Comment: I actually did try 100.0, here are the values:
`$currentyear = 2013
$rateamount = 56.5
$currentamount = 0.56`

Comment: What does `print_r(localeconv());` return for `decimal_point` as value? My guess is that your locale settings have comma as decimal separator and therefore the part after the comma is cut away.

Comment: Here's the entire output, `Array ( [decimal_point] => . [thousands_sep] => [int_curr_symbol] => [currency_symbol] => [mon_decimal_point] => [mon_thousands_sep] => [positive_sign] => [negative_sign] => [int_frac_digits] => 127 [frac_digits] => 127 [p_cs_precedes] => 127 [p_sep_by_space] => 127 [n_cs_precedes] => 127 [n_sep_by_space] => 127 [p_sign_posn] => 127 [n_sign_posn] => 127 [grouping] => Array ( ) [mon_grouping] => Array ( ) )`

Comment: Strangely it works fine at, http://writecodeonline.com/php/:
`$yearnow = date("Y");
$ratedate = 2013;
$rateamount = 56.5;

if ($yearnow == $ratedate) {
        $currentyear = $ratedate;
        $currentamount = $rateamount / 100;
} else {
    $currentyear = "";
    $currentamount = 0;
}
echo $currentyear . "<br />";
echo $currentamount;`
`2013
0.565`

Comment: Not here though, http://viper-7.com/

Comment: Maybe its the following php.ini setting: `precision`. 
Try the following before your code: `ini_set('precision', 14);` or check current setting by `print_r(ini_get('precision'))`

Comment: You are either truncating the number on output or `$mileagerates->Rates->Mileage_Rate` is converted to an integer before dividing.

Comment: `echo $mileagerates->Rates->Mileage_Rate;` = 56.5, where would the integer conversion take place?

Answer (score -2):

Probably it is the php.ini setting for `precision`.

Check the current setting by doing:

```
print_r(ini_get('precision'));
```

And set with

```
ini_set('precision', 14);
```

to a higher value, default should actually be 14 by the [php docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.precision).

Comment: It's currently set at 14:
`print_r(ini_get('precision'));` = 14

Comment: ; The number of significant digits displayed in floating point numbers.
; http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.precision
precision = 14

Comment: Then I'm now also out of ideas, that was the only way I was able to reproduce the issue :-/ 
http://codepad.org/K32VAy2u

Comment: Oddly if I change it to 20, I get 0.56000000000000005329.